# How to debug specific file with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have to cpp files (main and functions) and I make them to build a exe file (code) and two object files (main.o and functions.o).

How can I debug specific file "functions.cpp" from gdb command line?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile your files with gcc's `-g3` option. After this start `gdb <exename>`. You can then set breakpoint in your file inside gdb by something like `b functions.cpp:36` if you want the exe to break on line 36 of functions.cpp. You can set breakpoints to particular function calls as well, such as `b func()`. Then run the program using `r <options that exename takes>`.